# KSQL Stream output Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Hi i have Left Join Ksql Stream ( SEARCHREQUESTDTO)  with a Ksql Table (NGINX_TABLE). with following ksql command

```
CREATE STREAM NIGINX_SEARCH_QUERY AS \
  SELECT  *\
  FROM SEARCHREQUESTDTO\
  LEFT JOIN NGINX_TABLE\
    ON SEARCHREQUESTDTO.sessionid = NGINX_TABLE.sessionid;
```

Resulting Stream NIGINX_SEARCH_QUERY successfully. also i can see NIGINX_SEARCH_QUERY topic using show topic command in Ksql terminal.

[image]

**when i try to connect kafka consumer to this topic consumer is not able to fetch any data.**

but print NIGINX_SEARCH_QUERY command showing data is publishing in this topic.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do `CREATE STREAM ... WITH (kafka_topic='...')`?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, it makes it harder to follow your question. Copy and paste the text into your question and use code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

If `PRINT` shows output then the topic *does exist* and *has data*.

If your consumer doesn't show output then that's an error with your consumer. So I would rephrase your question as, I have a Kafka topic that my Consumer does not show data for.

I would use [`kafkacat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/) to check the topic externally:

```
      kafkacat -b kafka-broker:9092 -C -K: \
      -f '\nKey (%K bytes): %k\t\nValue (%S bytes): %s\n\Partition: %p\tOffset: %o\n--\n' \
      -t NIGINX_SEARCH_QUERY
```

Comment: I tried to run kafkacat command and successfully printing  all message from   NIGINX_SEARCH_QUERY topic.                                                                            Still not sure why my java consumer and s3 connector not getting data from this topic.

Comment: issue was with my kafka consumer broker. now able to fetch data from this topic

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what was wrong and (if not obvious) how you fixed it?